# Find records dated before today

Tags: text-processing, date

how to find record form bellows data  having "Last Date" before today's date. i.e : if today date is 09-04-2014 then finding record having "Last Date" before 09-04-2014

-

```
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 30-04-2014
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 18-03-2014
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 18-02-2013
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 18-05-2015
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 01-05-2012
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 09-04-2014
```

Expected output will be:

```
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 18-03-2014
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 18-02-2013
--
Email ID : abc@domain.com 
Last Date : 01-05-2012
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is with Perl.  We read chunks of your input having set the input record seperator to "--" as you data suggests.  We reformat your Day-Month-Year date into a form we can numerically, relationally compare; viz. YYYYMMDD.  Overall:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @t = localtime();
my $today = sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d", $t[5] + 1900, $t[4] + 1, $t[3] );

local $/ = "--"; #...record separator...

while (<>) {
    if (m{Last Date : (\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)}) {
        my $then = sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d", $3, $2, $1 );
        print if ( $then < $today );
    }
}
1;
```

Assuming you nae the script 'myfilter' you can execute by piping you input data to the program or simply doing:

```
$ myfilter inputdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as elegant as the Perl solution, but the same can be done with Awk with essentially the same algorithm:

```awk
BEGIN{
    FS      = " : |\n"
    RS      = "--\n?"; 
    Padding = " 00 00 00"; 
    Today   = mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d") Padding);
}
{
    Last_date = gensub(/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/, "\\3 \\2 \\1", "g", $4); 
        if (mktime(Last_date Padding) < Today) {
        sub(/\n$/, "", $0); 
        print Sep $0;
        Sep = "--\n"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -MTime::Local -nle '
BEGIN {
    $/ = "--"
}

($dd,$mm,$yy) = (localtime)[3..5];
$today = timelocal(0,0,0,$dd,$mm,$yy);
$h{$1} = $_ if /Last Date : (.*)$/;

END {
    print $h{$_} for grep {
        ($d,$m,$y)=split "-",$_;
        timelocal(0,0,0,$d,$m-1,$y) < $today;
    } keys %h
}' file
```

Here I use `timelocal()` function of core module `Time::Local` to convert date to epoch, it will handle the case when input date is not valid date.